# Get value on change drop down list with dynamic table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dynamic table, I add new row on click without problem. I have a column named service that contains a drop down list, and a column named price. Each time i make a selection the price change according the corresponding value in the service drop down.

My issue is :  For example if I select a service (Dentist) his price is shown in the column price. After I add a new row and I select another service (Orthopedist) his price is shown in the column price and the price of (Dentist) is removed to get the price of (Orthopedist). This is done for all new rows I add.

How can i keep the price for each service in all rows ?

```js
var numRows = 1,
    ti = 2;

function addRow() {
  $('#addr' + numRows).html("<td><select class='service form-control' onChange='getPrice(this.value);'><option value='' hidden></option><?php foreach($serv as $s){?><option  value='<?=$s->id?>'><?=$s->insumservicio?></option><?php }?></select></td><td class='total-pag-seg'><input  name='totalpagseg" + numRows + "' type='text' class='price form-control' value='' tabindex='" + (ti++) + "' /></td>");

  $('#turf tr:last').after('<tr id="addr' + (numRows + 1) + '" class="calculation visible"></tr>');
  numRows++;
}

function getPrice(val) {
  var insurance = "<?=$insurance?>";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo site_url('
    admin / getPrice ');?>',
    data: {
      id: val,
      insurance: insurance
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#turf").find('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input.price').val(data);
      });
    };

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="turf">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="add_row"> New row</button></td>
      <td>Service</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='addr1' class="calculation visible">
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <select class="service form-control" onChange="getPrice(this.value);">
<option value="" hidden></option>
<?php foreach($serv as $s){?>
<option  value="<?=$s->id?>"><?=$s->insumservicio?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="price" tabindex="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr2' class="calculation visible">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you give your generated HTML instead of the PHP...?

Comment: Sorry I missed some part of my js. Behold is my fiddle of the generating html :  https://jsfiddle.net/jccz1syf/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example can guide you:

```
onChange='getPrice(this);'

function getPrice(dropDown) {
  var insurance = "<?=$insurance?>";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo site_url('
    admin / getPrice ');?>',
    data: {
      id: dropDown.value,
      insurance: insurance
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $($(dropDown).parents('tr')[0]).find('input.price').val(data);
    };

  });
}
```

Comment: mejiajuanbta thank you for your codes but it seems it's still not working

Comment: Did you change the event "onChange(this.value)" by "onChange(this)" at both places you are using it?